# Starting thingsboard service on windows Error 1067

Tags: thingsboard

I am getting the below error when I run `net start thingsboard`

```
A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

Comment: please check your logs and add more info here.

Comment: Logs shows message" Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required"  but when i change it to 1.7 it gives error because Jdk 1.8 is required for  thingsboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem  was with windows service java wrapper
I was able to run thingsboard from command line with out using service  wrapper using below command :

```
SET BASE=C:\thingsboard
SET LOADER_PATH=%BASE%\conf,%BASE%\extensions
SET SQL_DATA_FOLDER=%BASE%\data\sql
SET jarfile=%BASE%\lib\thingsboard.jar
SET installDir=%BASE%\data
java -jar thingsboard.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same Problem that I solved by giving correct path of java in 
**Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System\Advanced system settings\Advanced\Environmental Variables\System variables**

In system variable select **Path** and click on **Edit** and give your java version path
for example mine is:
**C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin**

if this is not working check whether multiple java versions are available or not.
**there should not be multiple java path in Environment Variables**  if its there delete others and let only correct path